# stopPropagation() "Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree" : what does it means?

Tags: jquery, event-propagation

I don't really understand what e.stopPropagation() do.

If I have a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4xG3a/2/) using `return false` to the handler I should get what I want (prevent the default link behaviour, so it doesnt "call" the next href location) :

```
<a id="myLink" href="http://www.google.com">Go to google</a>​

$('#myLink').click(function (e) {
    alert("No, you don't go to Google");
    return false;
});​
```

Adding `e.stopPropagation()` what can I get? Can you give to me a solid example showing to me what `e.stopPropagation()` can do?

Comment: if you `return false`, then that's same as `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` since it's a jQuery handler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easy, `stopPropagation` stops any events bubbling up to its container, its container's container etc etc.

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/5B7sw/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <button id="propagate">Propagate</button>
    <button id="nopropagate">Do not Propagate</button>
</div>
```

and js:

```
$('#container').click(function(){
   console.log('container click') ;
});


$('#propagate').click(function(){
   console.log('propagateclick');
});


$('#nopropagate').click(function(e){
   console.log('nopropagateclick');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Clicking the button title "propagate" (default behaviour) will write "propagate click" and "containerclick" to the console. Clicking the button which includes a call to `e.stopPropagation()` will not print the "container click" message as propagation up to the container has been halted.

Comment: Would be nice to know how jQuery team avoid this problem, using the solo preventDefault(); in fact they should use "return false" in some manner, wich call doing the same things as prevent+stoppropagation! This is interessant...

Answer (score 1):

In your example `e.stopPropagation()` would do nothing.

`e.stopPropagation()` may be used in case of nested element to prevent other element from receiving the event.

Answer (score 0):

Its not what you think it is..

stop propogation means that the same event will not propogate to its parent tag.

Answer (score 0):

event.stopPropagation() will prevent the event from bubbling up through its ancestors. What this means that any handlers attached to ancestors using [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live) matching the child element in question will not fire. Here is a demo to illustrate this fact: http://jsfiddle.net/fSBGC/6/